# How to use LRU cache for non-hashable lists?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

The levenshtein distance **for characters in strings** can be computed with the `lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import zip_longest

@lru_cache(maxsize=4095)
def ld(s, t):
    """
    Levenshtein distance memoized implementation from Rosetta code:
    https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python
    """
    if not s: return len(t)
    if not t: return len(s)
    if s[0] == t[0]: return ld(s[1:], t[1:])
    l1 = ld(s, t[1:])      # Deletion.
    l2 = ld(s[1:], t)      # Insertion.
    l3 = ld(s[1:], t[1:])  # Substitution.
    return 1 + min(l1, l2, l3)
```

E.g.

```
>>> ld("hello how are the you ?", "how Halo how you are the ?")
13
```

However if I want to track the **distance between 2 lists of words** instead of characters in strings, without the `lru_cache` it works:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import zip_longest

#@lru_cache(maxsize=4095)
def ld(s, t):
    """
    Levenshtein distance memoized implementation from Rosetta code:
    https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python
    """
    if not s: return len(t)
    if not t: return len(s)
    if s[0] == t[0]: return ld(s[1:], t[1:])
    l1 = ld(s, t[1:])      # Deletion.
    l2 = ld(s[1:], t)      # Insertion.
    l3 = ld(s[1:], t[1:])  # Substitution.
    return 1 + min(l1, l2, l3)
```

Usage:

```
 >>> ld("hello how are the you ?".split(), "how Halo how you are the ?".split())
```

However, without the LRU cache, it's not going to work with longer list of words.

And with the LRU cache, it throws a unhashable type error:

```
>>> ld("hello how are the you ?".split(), "how Halo how you are the ?".split())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1de95d00ebae> in <module>
----> 1 ld("hello how are the you ?".split(), "how Halo how you are the ?".split())

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to make the list of strings comparison hashable such that the `lru_cache` can be used?
- If it's not possible to somehow hash the list of words, how should I go about computing the distance efficiently to find the distance between two lists of words?  Only through dynamic programming?

Comment: you can probably just pass tuples (_hashable_) instead of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not modifying the lists, but only slicing, you may pass tuples, which are hashable.

```py
s = "hello how are the you ?".split()
t = "how Halo how you are the ?".split()
ld(tuple(s), tuple(t))
```

Otherwise, you may avoid using lru_cached functions by using loops with extra space, where you memoize calculations

Comment: Ah yes, it immutables tuples of strings are hashable!! =)